# how to get error message if record is already present in table in jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, html, sql, jsp

I have an `index.jsp` page from where I am inserting name and id into oracle table. I am able to insert successfully, but when user enters same employee id again `index.jsp` page redirects to tomcat error page says

`HTTP Status 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint`

I want to display an error note within `index.jsp` when user enters id which is already present in database.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body><center>
  <H1>Inserting record into a Database</H1>
       <%@ page language="java" %>
        <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
         <%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager.*" %>

            <% 
        int flag=0;
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        Connection con= null;
        ResultSet rs= null;
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("hostname","user","admin");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();

            String id = request.getParameter("id");  
            String name= request.getParameter("name");


            ResultSet resultset = 
                    rs=st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO employee (employeeid,employeename)VALUES ('"+id+"','"+name+""); 
            out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");

       %> 
 </center>           
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is more towards the architectural implementation of the application. Typical issue of **not implementing validation in your application**. have you implemented validations ?

Comment: And you should avoid java code in presentation layer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: Use java `try.. catch ..finally` to process errors and ensure proper connection state, close it for example.

Comment: Does any of the below answer solved your problem ? If yes then you can accept it so that it will be beneficial for the others having same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `try-catch` block to handle the exception.

What you can do to prevent it from coming is to check if the record is already present in table or not.

If the same `id` is present then do not execute the insert operation.

```
try{
        int flag=0;
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        Connection con= null;
        ResultSet rs= null;
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("hostname","user","admin");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();

        String id = request.getParameter("id");  
        String name= request.getParameter("name");

        // Check if the "id" is already present in table or not
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employeeid" = id );   
        if (!rs.next() ) {

            // id is not present then insert the new record
            rs = st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO employee (employeeid,employeename)VALUES ('"+id+"','"+name+""); 
            System.out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");

        } else{

            // id is already present then show the error message
            System.out.println("Data is already present in table!");
        }

} catch(Exception e){

    // Handle any other exception occuring 
    System.out.println("Exception : " + e.printStackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prakash .. this was useful for me ...it worked for me.. sorry for the late response as i was out of town for the past week :).

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the code in try and catch block ,when the control goes to catch block handle the exception and display the message you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific, handle the exception **SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException**. This exception indicates that an integrity constraint (foreign key, primary key or unique key) has been violated.

```
try{
    int flag=0;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    Connection con= null;
    ResultSet rs= null;
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("hostname","user","admin");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();

        String id = request.getParameter("id");  
        String name= request.getParameter("name");


        ResultSet resultset = 
                rs=st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO employee (employeeid,employeename)VALUES ('"+id+"','"+name+""); 
        out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");

   }catch(SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e ){
        //Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());//you can modify the output as per your requirement.
   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit ... i tried using this exception handling method it worked..